# How do I make `mousemove` fire only when I move to the next element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I stop `mousemove` from firing inside the same HTML table cell, and only fire when I move to the next cell?

This is for a pixel art type of project. I have this function that allows a user to draw on a `table` by clicking and dragging (changing the background color of individual cells). It also allows for erasing (odd click adds, even click removes color).

**The Problem**: When clicking individual cells sometimes the color flickers or doesn't change at all.
**The diagnosis**: After testing it out I realised the problem occurs when the `mouseup` event fires after `mousemove` but within the same cell - ie your mouse moves a tiny bit, registering a `mousemove` before the `mouseup`. Being in the same cell the `mouseIsDown` registers `false` and counteracts the color change.

How do I stop this from happening?

```js
// click and drag draw/erase function
function drag () {
    let mouseIsDown = true;
    let clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    $('td')
    .on('mousemove', function(){
        if (mouseIsDown){
            if (!clicks){
                // Change background color of cell
                $(this).css('backgroundColor', selectedColor);
            } else {
                // On second click return color to default (erase)
                $(this).css('background-color', '');
            }
            // Fire `if` event on odd clicks
            $(this).data('clicks', !clicks);
        }
    })
    .on('mousedown', function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            mouseIsDown = true;
        })
        .on('mouseup', function(){
            mouseIsDown = false;
        });
    pixelCanvas.on('mouseleave', function(){
        mouseIsDown = false;
    });
}

// Event listener click delegated
pixelCanvas
    .on('click', 'td', draw)
    .on('mousedown', 'td', drag);
```

Currently my best idea is to store the start and end cell index and maybe use that to set a condition not to execute `drag()` if it starts and ends in the same cell. But i'm neither sure how to implement this nor if it will work.

Any solutions or recommendations?

Comment: It sounds like you want `mouseover` not `mousemove`....

Comment: How about reading the docs? [Mouse Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) Looks like `.mouseleave` is what you're after.

Comment: I have been reading the docs, but obviously I didn't understand enough to figure out the solution. But thanks for the guidance. Sometimes it's not evident for someone new to this.